# issue with -Apple-Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, xcode6

I am developing an app for `iOS` using `parse and stripe`. I have to implement the `payment` functionality. Hence I downloaded sample `project` form [Parse.Com](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore)

After reading `readme`.md I Have successfully completed `step1`.

But in step 2 when i build and run my Project i Get `Linker Errors`.

I am unable to find any solution any one please suggest what to do.

[ScreenShot of Errors](http://screencast.com/t/rGvDDFFcXXc)

Comment: If after importing all the framework, still getting the error, then clean the project and restart, else quit the xcode and restart

Comment: There are several "step 1" instances in the `README.md`.  Which one are you referring to?  Did you run the shell script in Terminal?  Did you add the ID and Key to the `xcconfig` files?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that Parse is being included in the build target? It looks like Parse can't find the classes referenced because you didn't include it in your build target.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/tUv6x7ZPvp48  i have uploaded all the frameworks... still i am getting the error

Comment: click the framework and make sure in the "file inspector" tab (first tab right sidebar) that your current target is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project in the navigator arear. Then an area containing targets and project is revealed. Then select your target and go to build phases tab. Then open up the link binary with libraries. There import the frameworks or libs you need for the project(The required frameworks might be listed in the readme.md file). This might solve your problem. Hope this helps